# Cloud Armor Bypass?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-armor

Supposing I need to turn off Cloud Armor for a while. Will it be bypassed and traffic routed to the HTTPs load balancer? Or will the LB also be bypassed and traffic go straight to actual public IPs of Compute Instances?
What are the side effects of turning off Armor temporarily?

Answer (score 1):

If you disable Cloud Armor, the load balancer will continue to process traffic.

The only side effect is the Cloud Armor rules will not be processed.